# Report Builder - Datediff between 2 columns

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, report, builder, datediff

I have created a report with Report Builder 3.0 using columns groups.
The columns retrieve a datetime field. I would like to calculate the date difference between two columns.
For each individual the report should display 1 row and 2 columns. One of the columns can have null values. In this case, no calculation needs to be performed.
I cannot perform any calculation at the dataset level because I am using a stored procedure that I cannot modify.

I have tried to perform a calculation but the values are not correct. Moreover, the results are also changing if the Sort values change.

[Random sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwu89.jpg)

Basically, I need to calculate the different between the 2 columns at the row level.

Any ideas?

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMxss.jpg)

Comment: You need to show the expressions you're using in the appointment and difference columns before we can start finding out what's going on here. That said, I'm not sure a matrix is the correct approach; a simple table seems better. Also I really don't like the look of the sum expression in the Individual column either; I'm assuming this represents a customer/account number...

Comment: Yeah something must be going wrong if you're having 2nd appointments before 1st appointments. Need to see the fields and the expressions really. Once you sort the fields out a datediff expression should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Check the screenshot Desired output to understand why I have chosen the Matrix.
So far, I am trying to get the correct results by using a custom code.

Comment: Public Function GetDate(ByVal appDate as Date, ByVal appType As String) As Date
If appType = "1st Appointment" Then
If appDate = Nothing
D1 = Nothing
Return Nothing
Else
D1 = appDate
End If
ElseIf appType = "2nd Appointment" Then
If appDate = Nothing
D2 = Nothing
Return Nothing
Else
D2 = appDate
End If
End If
Return appDate
End Function
     
Public Function GetDateDiff() AS String
Dim dt As Integer
If D1 = Nothing
return "-"
ElseIf D2 = Nothing
return "-"
Else
dt = DateDiff("D", D1, D2)
End If
Return dt.ToString()
End Function